# Running a clojure repository on Github

Tags: git, github, clojure, leiningen

I am a newbie to Github. I want to run [this tutorial](https://github.com/puredanger/poly-timing) repo from Github. 
I do `lein run poly-timing-master/` in the directory where i have downloaded and extracted the zip file and i get this error in the terminal:

`No :main namespace specified in project.clj.`

Am i doing the running process correctly?

Comment: Try `lein run` alone.  Based on a quick look at project.clj and core.clj, that should work.  I'm not sure where "-master" came from.  That's surely wrong.  (`lein repl` may be worth trying, too.  Then you can invoke functions in the source from the prompt.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

type the following at your shell/command prompt

```
git clone https://github.com/puredanger/poly-timing
cd poly-timing
lein deps
lein run
```

you should see the following

```
Compiling poly-timing.core
## Value-based dispatch

Benchmarking case 1st
WARNING: Final GC required 1.438013251625518 % of runtime
WARNING: Final GC required 13.265534855967589 % of runtime
Evaluation count : 26507544 in 6 samples of 4417924 calls.
             Execution time mean : 21.775064 ns
    Execution time std-deviation : 1.152629 ns
   Execution time lower quantile : 20.008462 ns ( 2.5%)
   Execution time upper quantile : 22.995363 ns (97.5%)
                   Overhead used : 1.940065 ns
...
```

Comment: I just did out of curiosity directly `lein run` (without doing `lein deps` before it) and it worked also fine. Do i miss something if i don't do `lein deps` first?

Comment: lein deps checks and downloads any missing dependencies. It worked because you didn't have any missing dependencies.